# How do I disable automatic type creation in Titan 0.4?

Tags: java, configuration, titan, tinkerpop

How can I disable automatic type creation in Titan?

I modified the [GraphOfTheGodsFactory](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/master/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java) example to this effect, by inserting the line

```
config.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.AUTO_TYPE_KEY, "none");
```

but this does not seem to have the desired effect, as per the rexster console below:

```
rexster[groovy]> saturn = g.V("name", "saturn").next()
==>v[4]
rexster[groovy]> saturn.setProperty("someNewProp", "xyz")
==>null
rexster[groovy]> saturn.map
==>{someNewProp=xyz, name=saturn, age=10000, type=titan}
rexster[groovy]> saturn.addEdge("someNewLabel", g.V("name", "cerberus").next())
==>e[1G51-4-7I][4-someNewLabel->44]
rexster[groovy]> g.config.defaultTypeMaker
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.blueprints.BlueprintsDefaultTypeMaker@5b97e4fa
```

I am using `titan-server-0.4.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on how you are creating your graph instance with the `GraphOfTheGodsFactory` and how you are connecting the graph in Rexster, but assuming you ran your modified `GraphOfTheGodsFactory`, created the graph and then connected it to Rexster to that graph, you would also need to set `auto-type` to `none` in `rexster.xml` for that setting to be respected by Rexster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I create the graph by compiling and running the modified GraphOfTheGodsFactory, and then I connect to it from a Rexster console, using the command `g = TitanFactory.open("/tmp/titangotg")`. So if I understand correctly, Rexster has to be told the config of the graph it connects to?

Comment: Ok...now I understand.  You need to supply a properties file to `TitanFactory.open()`.  In that properties file you should include configuration options for your BerkeleyDB graph at `/tmp/titangotg` as well as your `auto-type=none` setting.  The `auto-type` setting is not persisted with the graph on creation.  It must be configured for each graph instance that is opened.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to write the config to file at the time of creation?

Comment: If you really wanted to write out the `BaseConfiguration` instance, it's just an Apache Configuration object (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/index.html), so one way would be to just do: `ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(config)` which will give you a standard `java.util.Properties` object.  From there you can write to `OutputStream`.  There are likely other ways to do this with the Apache Configuration classes as well, but this was the first one that came to mind.

Comment: That raises a `ConversionException`, but anyway, thanks for your explanations and help.

Comment: Huh....i'm sure you can get it to write out to a standard properties file.  In the worst case, just iterate the keys/values and write them to a file manually.